# Graphics in C programming

Tags: c, pixel

How can I draw just a pixel in C programming?

I feel if I know this, I can build a whole lot of codes for drawing many objects line, circle etc.

I am using fedora 17 (linux) on intel chip.

Am I being too hopeful?

Comment: do you use libraries like OpenGL ?

Comment: what did you tried to draw a pixel ? and Which plat form are you using ..?

Comment: You will get lots of hits if you google "How can I draw just a pixel in C program".

Comment: Here You found [C code that draws 25000 (NPTS) random black pixels](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=269406). this might helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with OpenGL.

1. [Read this wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started)
2. install your suitable graphics driver from [Here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer)
3. [Start programming](http://www.linuxforu.com/2013/04/graphics-programming-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to draw pixel on a screen, or text file, or a picture format file (jpg, bmp)? If it's screen you would be better off using a library which allows you draw graphics such as SDL. If it's a text file, well there is not much to explain except to open a file and write to it. If it's picture format output there are other libraries out there that would create picture files for you. doing a quick search I found this: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There's not a standard for graphics programming in C, it completely depends on what environment you are running in.   If you're targeting Linux, then that usually means X11.   Read up on Xlib, or a widgit library like Qt or Gtk.

Comment: could you tell me more about 'environment' ? is it graphic card environment you are talking about? does windows and linux use different environment? please help.

Comment: By "environment" I just mean "the context in which your program will be run".